# Most Elegant Way to Populate Nulls from Reference Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables like so:

Table 1:

```
Column 1  Column 2
A            1
B            NULL
C            3
D            4
```

Table 2:

```
Column 1  Column 2
A            1
B            2
C            3
D            4
```

I receive the data in table 2 on a time delay, and what I need to do when I receive it is populate the null values in Table 1 with the data in table 2.  Is there an elegant way to do this in Standard SQL without making temporary tables or using sub-queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an insert trigger on Table2, which updates Table1.Column2 where Table1.Column 2 is null?

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't familiar with "Insert Into".  Looks like it'll work for my use if I can only have it apply to nulls (case statement?).

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a [MERGE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement):

```sql
MERGE dataset.table1 AS t1
USING dataset.table2 AS t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t2.column2 = t1.column2
```

Take a look at the supported actions you can perform; if you want to insert new rows, you can do that using MERGE as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`UPDATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) statement from the [DML (Data Manipulation Language)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) and update Table 1 in place.

It is not clear from your question how you receive data from Table 2, so I will assume that you have a temporary table called `Table2`. You will have to `JOIN` `Table1` and `Table2` in order to find which rows have NULL values, i.e `Table1.Column2 IS NULL`. Then update `Column2` in those rows using the value in `Table2`. It should be something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column2 = Table2.Column2
FROM
  Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(Column1)
WHERE
  Table1.Column2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct use of [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) statement would be

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table1` a
SET Column_2 = b.Column_2
FROM `project.dataset.table2` b
WHERE a.Column_1 = b.Column_1
AND a.Column_2 IS NULL
```